# throw exception to change password in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, exception, ldap, throw, change-password

i wanna ask again. How can i resolve this problem

[Eror Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv6L5.png)

always find error, and i won't stop. I must be try with help from you guys.
after you look my error, this is my code:

```js
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace FormsAuthAd
{
    public class ChangePasswordPSI
    {
        public bool ChangePass(HttpSessionState Session, string OldPassword, string NewUPassword)
        {
            string Domain = Session["domain"].ToString();
            string Username = Session["username"].ToString();
            
            try
            {
                string ldapPath = "LDAP://MyDomain.com";
                DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, Domain + "\\" + Username, OldPassword);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(user);
                    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + Username + ")";
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        object ret = user.Invoke("ChangeUserPassword", new object[] { OldPassword, NewUPassword });
                        user.CommitChanges();
              

                        return true;
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return false;
        }        
        
    }
}
```

can somebody tell me, what should i do?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using try..catch and cannot find where exactly the exception occurred, delete try and catch and execute the code again. In your example, it might happen on `Invoke("ChangeUserPassword"...` - as far as I see the method name should be "ChangePassword"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180896(v=vs.80).aspx